# Intercepting media file requests from WebView and replacing them with local files in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm working on a Xamarin Forms project on Android that has a WebView which loads my website to play videos. Before loading the WebView, I'm downloading the mp4 files from the server into the app data folder. Then overriding ShouldInterceptRequest method to replace the video request with the local ones. Here is the code for ShouldInterceptRequest:

```
public override WebResourceResponse ShouldInterceptRequest(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
{
    string url = request.Url.ToString();

    if (IsRemoteVideo(url))
    {
        String relativeUrl = url.Replace(HOSTNAME, string.Empty);

        if (App._downloadedMediaFiles.Any(m => m.Key == relativeUrl))
        {
            string localVideoPath = App._downloadedMediaFiles.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == relativeUrl).Value;

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localVideoPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            return new WebResourceResponse("video/mp4", "UTF-8", fileStream);
        }
    }

    return base.ShouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```

But the WebView can't load the video and it shows 0kb in the developer tools.

Is this even possible? If yes what is the right way to do this?

Comment: According to the documentation the encoding parameter should null for binary types like images. But I don't think this is the reason for your problem. Have you checked that your FileStream of the video works correctly?

Comment: Hi @Robert, Thanks for the comment. I set the encoding to null. but still it doesn't play. I even tried it with MemoryStream. Still same result. Both FileStream and MemoryStream show the correct length after loading. So I guess they work properly.

Comment: You ca try to manually set content-type and content-length header on the WebResourceResponse: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77133909/150978

Comment: I tried that also. didn't work